# Rename filename having double space to single

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I have 500 files in a folder, few of them have double space between the name. I need to rename from double to single space.

'acd  dg_1.jpg'
'dfs_sd as  j.jpg'
'1_image.jpg'

```
import os
Path='folderpath'
Name = os.listdir(Path)
for filename in Names:
    os.rename(filename,filename.replace("  "," "))
```

Not working

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate `Names` while your list is `Name`.